# Partial View and View to be display on master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

im new here.
i would like to ask about partial view.
I created 2 partial view( 1 for Link to another pages, and another 1 is pages)
i call those 2 partial view in to 1 view and put it into my master page.
now i want to click the link in partial view and show it in master page. how to do this?

sorry for my bad english. 
hope u guys understand..

Best Regards,

Sen

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly ,you organized the partial views and your master page in a wrong way and you expect something wrong.

You should create a MasterPager (or **_Layout.cshtml** file in Razor) with a just one PartialView for your menus/lins(lets say it **MenuBar**). Your _Layout.cshtml also should contains a **@RenderBody** which is responsible for different page contents.

After that you just create your pages and point them to user your masterpage (it is done by default by Razor). After that whenever you click on each link on your MenuBar , you redirected to the page which is pointed to. 
At server and on rendering phase, The MVC starts to render the page from your master page (so it contains the **Menu Bar** automatically) and when it reachs the **@RenderBody** line , it renders your main page content instead.

**EDIT**

you can check this link for a full tutorial about layouting : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx or
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor

But

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.
erm.. can u give me example?
i want have menubar in the master page, after that in masterpage when i click the menubar, it will show view/partialview within the masterpage and contain the menubar..

Comment: I edited the post and add two usefull links . check them and let me know if you could solve your problem or not